# My site goes to login page when loaded in an iframe in chrome 84.0.4147.125

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

We are trying to load our site in an iframe and the site goes to login page when checked in chrome Version 84.0.4147.125. The page loads fine in other browsers. Please help in fixing this.

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: We are just adding our url to the iframe to load , with a valid token, so the page goes to dashboard in other browsers and in chrome it goes to the login page, have to know the reason for this, pls help

Comment: can you provide teh link?

Comment: I am having the same issue related to cookies being handled for IFRAMEs in Chrome 84. What is the best IIS or web.config setting for <sessionState> for cookies? Lax does not work, and Google's suggestion is not supported by IIS by supplying None;Secure. IIS only supports one or the other.

Comment: Having the same problem here since updating chrome.  Site loaded in an iframe does not keep session.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found researching this it's related to needing to set the samesite=none header on cookies if it's loaded in an iframe.  Since session id is stored in a cookie, that won't work either.  Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution that works with .net 4.6.2 which is what we're on, so we have to upgrade everything to 4.7.2 to be able to set the cookie's SameSite property.

For reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/google-chrome-84-released-next-week-with-revived-samesite-cookie-changes